# Resize window size in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I am facing the problem in window resizing for multi-browser support.

The given below image will show the problem,

[image]

In the image the content loading sizing is not unique in all browsers .It is marked in the RED  color and also I pointed in the black color dots in the corner too.

I already have a html `page with` the fixed size as `(700px,120px)`.I need to resize the window based on the `html page` size. This `html` will be the content of the window.

I reffered this from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeto

I need the inner content loading window must be same for all browsers. How can I achieve this.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: You have very little control over how large a window really is. As you can see you can resize the window even. I think the best you can do is make the window large enough and deal with minor changes in your CSS (get a center-center). As a minor side note: popups are quite annoying, is there another way you could do this?

Comment: not sure you can either as it will be determined on the users screen size if its smaller than what your trying to resize too etc and also that's browser for you. Also users dont liek it when you force a window to a sixe etc

Comment: The user can resize their browser window however they want to. Your website should be able to handle this nicely. (show scrollbars where appropriate, etc)

Comment: Can't you just create a div with fixed size and then center it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the size of the main browser window. The only "workaround" I can think of would be to set the page's size with CSS. It will not actually rescale the browser window, but it will force specific dimensions for your page. Try it out and see if it's sufficient. If not, I can't help.

```
html, body {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```